# How do I send an image via discord webhook using node-fetch?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, fetch, webhooks

```js
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const fs = require('fs')
var data = fs.createReadStream('2.png')
const fileSizeInBytes = data.size;
var URL = "apikey";
fetch(URL, {
     "method":"POST",
     "headers": {
         "Content-length": fileSizeInBytes,
         'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
         'Content-Disposition': 'form-data; name="2"; filename="2.png"'
         },
     "body": JSON.stringify({
        "file":data
      })
    })
    .then(res=> console.log(res))
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

how can I send images via discord webhook? I have tried the above and it does not work. and there are no proper examples on discord docs.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const formData = require('form-data');
const fs = require('fs')

const form = new formData();
form.append('file1', fs.createReadStream('./2.png')); // give absolute path if possible

var URL = "XYZ URL";

fetch(URL, {
    'method': 'POST',
    'body': form,
    headers: form.getHeaders()
})
.then(res=> console.log(res))
.catch(err => console.error(err));
```